# Export 3D data dxf file problems with elevation value

Tags: qgis-2, elevation, autocad

I have the problem that i can´t export a shp file into DXF and include the eleveation value I make all the procedure explane on "export 3D data dxf file 4" but each time I have the folow error:

```
C:\>ogr2ogr -f "dxf" C:\Users\Dieter\Desktop\Fuchstal50\HL1m.dxf
C:\Users\Dieter\Desktop\Fuchstal50\levelline1m\contour.shp -zfield "levelline"
ERROR 1: DXF layer does not support arbitrary field creation, field 'ID' not created.
ERROR 1: DXF layer does not support arbitrary field creation, field 'levelline' not created.
```

And when I import the file into Autodesk to see if I have import the elevation, is not elevation information X,Y are the coordinates numbers but Z is 000000?